# How to get the path of maven settings.xml programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Is  there a way to get the path of the maven `settings.xml` file in a java program like from default system property or maven options.I want to avoid getting that information from user through a configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the maven [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html),

> There are two locations where a `settings.xml` file may live:
>
> - The Maven install: `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml`
> - A user’s install: `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`

**To access `maven.home`**

```
System.getenv("M2_HOME");
```

**To access `user.home`**

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```